# Trouble with developing a network for linear regression

Tags: keras, neural-network, linear-regression

So I was given a dataset with basically one feature, and my task is to develop a  regression model using a neural network.

So far I have managed to deduce four more features, but I'm having trouble with the outputs I'm getting i.e, they deviate quite a bit from the actual output, thought they do seem to follow the same trend.

I was wondering if trying to figure out more features will help with this, or if there are any particular NN architecture tips I could use.

This is the network I'm using right now.

```
model1 = Sequential()

model1.add(Dense(128, input_dim = train_fin.shape[1], activation = 'relu'))

model1.add(Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))             
model1.add(Dropout(0.2))

model1.add(Dense(1, activation = 'linear'))

model1.compile(loss = 'mean_absolute_error', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['mean_absolute_error'])
```

Comment: Just want to point out that you are not actually busy with linear regression if your hidden layers contain non-linear activations, such as ReLU functions.

Comment: Also, if your goal is linear regression, you can achieve this with a single hidden layer using much less hidden units in the layer.

Comment: I tried this, and ended up getting even higher loss values than what I was getting before. Decreasing the number of neurons only seems to cause the loss to shoot up by quite a bit

Comment: This is quiet big network for one feature dataset. As one said earlier you are using non-linear activation functions, so it's not quite linear nn. Can you give us information about your data? What standardisation you use? Is it correctly normalized on train and test dataset?

Comment: I have a total of four features right now. I used sklearn's StandardScaler() function to scale my data. I don't think my problem is exactly a linear regression one, but i do have to predict a numeric value based on text data.